# Why does git merge-base only return one commit in this case?

Tags: git, git-merge

Consider the merge-bases of branches B and A in the following map:

```
     A0---------A1--A (topic)
    / \        /
---M0--\--M1--M (master)
    \   \      \
     B0--B1-----B (int)
```

The following git command identifies two merge-bases, M and A0:

```
$ git merge-base --all B A
```

But apparently git considers merge-base M "best" because the following command only returns it:

```
$ git merge-base B A
```

What makes M better than A0 to git? I can see that there are fewer parents involved but I do not see this consideration mentioned in the manual page for merge-base.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not what happens for me, `git merge-base --all int topic` on that graph produces both bases.

```
$ sh -x <<'EOD'
git init merge-base-test;cd $_
doit() { eval $*; git add .;shift $(($#-1)); git commit -m "$1"; }
doit touch M0
doit touch M1
doit touch M
git checkout -b topic :/M0
doit touch A0
git merge master -m A1
doit touch A
git checkout -b int :/M0
doit touch B0
git merge :/A0 -m B1
git merge master -m B
git merge-base --all int topic
EOD
```

edit: ah, I see, you're assuming there's some inherent ranking among all the best merge bases, that there's some reason to choose one base among peers.  There isn't.  When you only ask for ***a*** merge base `git merge-base` will just pick whatever shows up first while it's looking for common ancestry.  That's so often good enough that it's the default  behavior.

Comment: Worth noting: `git merge -s recursive` (the default) first merges all the merge bases, committing the result as a temporary commit. It then uses the committed temporary result as a new merge base for the merge. `git merge -s resolve` simply picks one at apparent-random, just like `git merge-base` without `--all`. Most other Git commands either pick one just like this, or misbehave because someone forgot to consider the multiple merge bases possibility. :-)

Comment: I see now that the man page does say "When the --all option is not given, it is unspecified which best one is output."